# Testing for effect sizes in R using wilcoxonpairedR

Tags: r

I've run some simple paired-sampled Wilcoxon tests in R, and now I want to test for effect sizes. I've been using `wilcoxonPairedR` from the `effsize` package, but somehow I can't get it to work on my data; I keep getting the error message `Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “SymmetryProblem” object: FALSE`.

Here is some sample data (note that there are NAs in Group B, which I filter out for the test below:

```
 exampledata <- tribble(~subject, ~group, ~Measure1, ~Measure2,
     "1", "A", .8, .23,
     "2", "B", NA, .79,
     "3", "A", .6, .28,
     "4", "B", NA, .18,
     "5", "A", .86, .90,
     "6", "A", .34, .23,
     "7", "B", NA, .12,
     "8", "B", NA, .27)
```

I run a paired Wilcoxon test to see if Measure 1 differs from Measure 2 between participants in Group A:

```
 wilcox.test(Measure1 ~ Measure2, subset(exampledata, group =="A"), paired=T)
```

I then test for effect size:

```
 wilcoxonPairedR(x = subset(exampledata, group == "A")$Measure1,
                 g = subset(exampledata, group == "A")$Measure2)
```

Which generates the error message. When I filter the data manually and then test using filtered subsets of data, it also doesn't work:

```
 exampledataA <- exampledata %>% filter(group == "A")

 wilcoxonPairedR(x = exampledataA$Measure1,
                 g = exampledataA$Measure2)
```

`Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “SymmetryProblem” object: FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the wrong arguments to both `wilcox.test()` and `wilcoxonPairedR()`. `wilcox.test()`'s formula interface expects a formula such as `measure1 ~ group`, whereas you are providing `measure1 ~ measure2`.  Likewise, in `wilcoxonPairedR()`, your `x` and `g` are both measures, whereas this function expects `x` to be a vector of measures, and `g` to be a corresponding vector of group labels.

Comment: This works, thank you! I un-spread the data and ran it so that `x = subset(exampledata, group == "A")$Value` and `g = subset(exampledata, group == "A")$Measure`.